# Is there any specific SW framework, libraries or algorithms designed for implementing a practical artificial general intelligence (AGI) system?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, agi, singularity, neuroscience

**Any (AGI)-KERAS like libraries useful to develop a real Artificial General Intelligence (AGI) system?** Any deep-learning framework to develop AGI applications? any real Transformer-based (like Chat-GPT) libraries that can be used to achieve a minimum level of Artificial General Intelligence?

Existing frameworks/algorithms used in NN, NLP, ML, etc are not enough in my opinion. In my opinion any framework has to be based on building blocks from: Cognitive Science, Neuroscience, Mathematics, Artificial Intelligence, Computer Science, psycology, sociology, etc.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: To me, it's not fully clear what you're asking here. What's the purpose of this question? Moreover, what does it mean "a theory designed for implementing a **practical** AGI system"?. Please, edit your post to clarify the rationale behind this post/question. Are you just curious? Have you done some research before asking the question? Please, take a look at this page too: https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I think so . I have rephrased it asking  for info on tools,libraries and algorithms really focusing on AGI and not on weak AI.

Comment: @RaulAlvarez Ok, then, please, revise also your title, because in the title you're asking for "theories", which are different from a software library, which is different from an "algorithm". You should also clarify whether you're looking for a "theoretical framework" or if by "framework" you mean a "software library". In any case, note that asking for tools here is generally off-topic, although this question will be kept, as this is about AGI (which is central to this website). Moreover, to improve this question, you should explain why you're interested in this (as I said in the last comment).

Comment: In any case, the closest thing to what you're asking really seems to be something like OpenCog, as suggested by one person below.

Comment: Well, nor really. I have reviewwed OpenCog websites and aproach and it only seems to me to be a "single" example.... the comunity should be able to find out other solutions (whatever they are) and compare them. For the time being (imho)  I don´t think this question is similar to any other on Stackexchange nor has been really anwered.... so I have rephrased it again to be in line with your suggestions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to my knowledge. The problem is that this is such an enormous task, it cannot really be tackled at once. So the obvious solution is to reduce the scope. In early AI people were using toy domains, whereas nowadays AI systems work more generally (but still perform better if the domain is restricted).

So while (slow) progress is being made putting the individual building blocks together, we're still a long way off building an overarching general system from them.

Comment: Yep, any solution has to deal with some kind of reduction in the "mind complexity" to make this problem manageable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Would OpenCog fit the bill? I have had tremendous amounts of trouble building up the demos, which include some non-AGI stuff, but if I’ve read the manual correctly, I think there’s something here — https://opencog.org/

Comment: Thanks! It may be a good start where some interesting issues are mentioned:    "One of the critical issues confronted in doing logical inference on large spatiotemporal knowledge bases is the fact that most real-world logical relationships are contextual in nature. Contextuality must be explicitly taken into account to make real-world inference tractable."  https://wiki.opencog.org/w/Real_World_Reasoning